How to plot maps from `tigris` and `osmdata` on the same map in R
I'm having trouble plotting data from the tigris and osmdata packages on the same figure. The goal is to have highways overlaying administrative boundaries.
I have included sample code below. I do not believe the issue is due to the objects having different CRS values. Thanks!
library(tidyverse)
# library(censusapi)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(ggmap)
library(osmdata)

# Define bounding box

vec_bbox <- c(
  xmin = -71.4, 
  ymin = 42.3,
  xmax = -71.0, # Longitude range
  ymax = 42.55  # Latitude range
)

res_st_bbox <- st_bbox(
  vec_bbox, crs = "NAD83"
) 

res_sfc_bbox <- st_as_sfc(res_st_bbox)

# Highways
osm_data_highways <- opq(bbox = vec_bbox) |> # "Boston, MA") %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway",
                  value = c("motorway") # , "trunk", "primary"
                  ) %>%
  osmdata_sf()

highways_sf <- osm_data_highways$osm_lines

highways_sf <- st_transform(highways_sf, crs = "NAD83")

# Get Town Data

ma_towns <- county_subdivisions(state = "MA",
                                county = "Middlesex",
                                year = 2019)

ma_towns_zoomed <- ma_towns[st_intersects(ma_towns, res_sfc_bbox, sparse = FALSE), ]


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ma_towns_zoomed,color = "black",
          fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = highways_sf, color = "blue") +
  theme_bw()



It's not entirely clear how your current output differs from your expected output. Do you want all highways to extend to the full extent of the admin boundaries? And have the highways restricted to within the admin boundaries? Or something else?

Thank you! You're correct. I thought the highways were mistakenly being plotted out into the water to the east of Boston. However, the county_subdivisions data just does a very poor job of mapping the coastline. When I plot urban_areas, I can see the Boston coastline much better, and this suggests the highways are being plotted correctly. Thanks!
